# proguard in android - should i obfuscate gson POJOs

Tags: gson, android-proguard

I am assuming i cannot obfuscate gson POJOs.  if i do then gson cannot do the object mapping and deserialize json to POJO, correct ? Is there any way to obfuscate POJOs then ? Also please let me know if my thoughts are correct that obfuscating POJOs should not be done and if so what would be the proguard command to keep all pojos.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

5 months too late but I ran into this issue and this was the first Google result.

My solution was just to keep all POJOs unobfuscated, the easiest way being to keep all classes that are in a "model" folder

```
-keep class com.example.myapp.**.model.** {*; }
```

This will keep all POJOs that are in any model package in your app.

Comment: since your using the -keep command your telling proguard not to obfuscate the model folder right ? why then do you say "keep all POJOs obfuscated". I thought keep preserves the classes.

Comment: Woops, meant UNobfuscated!

Comment: where do you put this line?

Comment: @klutch you put the line in your project-folder/app/proguard-rules.pro