# Proguard obfuscation creates fafal exception LinkedHashMap cannot be cast

Tags: java, android, proguard, obfuscation

I use Retrofit to catch a json string that fills a POJO

The POJO class is:

```
public class Entries{

    public ArrayList<Entry> entries;


    public Entry entry(int index){

        return entries.get(index);
   }
}
```

Calling the `entry()` method creates a Fatal Exception:
`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.example.model.Entry`

I tried this rule in the proguard rules file

```
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable,Signature,*Annotation*
```

but got no luck.

What is the proguard rule that would unlock the situation? Many thanks

**UPDATE**

Here is the solution:

```
-keep class com.example.myapp.**.model.** {*; }
```

Answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32852395/973237)